# Why parameters are sending out of Model hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I generated a scaffold, and now I am having the following problem:

When I submit my form, the parameters are being sent like this:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Vatzcb5tgTu2+wL1t6Of+FbIK8Ibp+tM03Naai4b2OU=", "role_id"=>"1", "model"=>"schema_migrations", "assignment"=>{"can_create"=>"1", "can_read"=>"1", "can_update"=>"1", "can_delete"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Assignment"}
```

Note that `role_id` and `model` are out of `assignments`. So when I use:

```
params.require(:assignment).permit(:role_id, :model, :can_create, :can_read, :can_update, :can_delete)
```

The `role_id` and `model` are not present in the structure. These fields are necessary to save the row in the database.

I need these two fields inside the `assignments` attribute.

Information about my situation:

My model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  validates_presence_of :role_id, :model
end
```

My view:

```
<%= f.label :role_id, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
<%= select_tag :role_id, options_for_select(@roles.collect{ |u| [u.title, u.id] }), :class => "form-control" %>

<%= f.label :model, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
<%= select_tag :model, options_for_select(@data_tables), :class => "form-control" %>
```

My controller:

```
def new
  @assignment = Assignment.new
  @data_tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
  @roles = Role.all
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is to use `<%= select_tag :role_id ...` instead of `<%= f.select :role_id ...`

Using your form builder `f` with the correct method `select` will correctly link to your model object and set the correct input fields names

Comment: ahhahahhha.. Thanks.. Its perfect what I need!!